# How to get the intime and outitme using sqlquery

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a table with fields name, id, date, intime/outtime, datetime.

In this, I need to find the first intime, last outtime and the duration between first intime and last outtime of every employee.

If the employee is swiped in, then this is his 1st intime. If he moved out then it is his outtime. So, at the end of the day, his final outtime and then the duration from 1st intime and last outtime has to be calculated.

When I took the minimum of datetime, I got the 1st intime. But, if I take the maximum of outtime I get the current status that can be in/out.

While, I need to get the last out time.

Comment: define duration. intime/outtime are two different columns or same columns ? if same, then whats the business to identify time as intime or outtime ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  select name,MAX(convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108)as outtime,MIN(convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108) as intime , 
  (MAX( convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108 ) - MIN( convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108 ) )AS duration from Table
```

OR

```
SELECT name,intime/outime 
 (SELECT MAX([convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108]) AS outtime FROM ... WHERE ...)
- (SELECT MIN([convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108]) AS inTime FROM ... WHERE ...)
 AS duration  from TABLE
```

Comment: hi this in/out is a single field which shows the status i get the intime as min(convert(char(8),DateTime,108) as intime

Comment: this will give the 1st in time and the last out time bu if the last is an in this will show as Out so i need to get that value

Comment: can u specify what u want properly or in brief? with some examples

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, date , MIN(convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108) AS intime , MAX(convert(char(8),datetimecolumn,108) AS outtime, (outtime -intime) as duration 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name, date
```

Comment: you able to find the answer? then add your answer and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  date,
  FirstInTime = MIN(CASE [intime/outtime] WHEN 1 THEN datetime END),
  LastOutTime = MAX(CASE [intime/outtime] WHEN 2 THEN datetime END)
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  name,
  date
```

If the first event is always an in-time, then the `FirstInTime` column could be defined simply as

```
  …
  FirstInTime = MIN(datetime),
  …
```